# jQuery AJAX call not works

Tags: jquery, ajax

Check the AJAX call bellow. Problem is AJAX post not sending data to my method "/CategoryResearch/Search" at all. As per my check I don't see any wrong with it.

Please let me know if you find any problem on it.

Thanks in advance

```
<script>    
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var _OperationName = "";
    var _calltype = "";
    var _page = "";
    var _keywords = "";
    var _type = "";
    var _location = "";
    var _condition = "";
    var _min = "";
    var _max = "";
    var _negative = "";
    var _minFeedback = "";
    var _maxFeedback = "";
    var _drange = "";
    var _categoryId = "";

    $(".SearchMainCategory, .SearchSubCategory").click(function () {
      _categoryId = $(this).find("#SearchLevel1CatId").val();
      if (typeof _categoryId === "undefined") {
        _categoryId = $(this).find("#SearchLevel2CatId").val();
      }

      _OperationName = "findItemsByCategory";
      _calltype = "categoryClick";
      _page = 1;

      $.post("/CategoryResearch/Search", 
        { 
          OperationName: _OperationName, 
          calltype: _calltype,
          page: _page, 
          keywords: _keywords, 
          type: _type, 
          location: _location, 
          condition: _condition, 
          min: _min, 
          max: _max,
          negative: _negative, 
          minFeedback: _minFeedback, 
          maxFeedback: _maxFeedback, 
          drange: _drange, 
          categoryId: _categoryId 
        }, 
      StartLoading())
      .done(function (data) {});    
    });   
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Open your browser console and try to trace the request in network tab

Comment: https://ibb.co/imy1Dw see this error come up on console

Comment: try to check your browser console while running your snippet. it will show you the errors( if any happen)

Answer (score 1):

As from your comments, I found you are calling a function which is undefined "StartLoading()" so I removed and now it works.

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var _operationname = "";
        var _calltype = "";
        var _page = "";
        var _keywords = "";
        var _type = "";
        var _location = "";
        var _condition = "";
        var _min = "";
        var _max = "";
        var _negative = "";
        var _minFeedback = "";
        var _maxFeedback = "";
        var _drange = "";
        var _categoryId = "";

        $(".SearchMainCategory, .SearchSubCategory").click(function () {
            _categoryId = $(this).find("#SearchLevel1CatId").val();
            if (typeof _categoryId === "undefined") {
                _categoryId = $(this).find("#SearchLevel2CatId").val();
            }

            _operationname = "findItemsByCategory";
            _calltype = "categoryClick";
            _page = 1;

            $.post("/CategoryResearch/Search", { OperationName: _operationname, calltype: _calltype, page: _page, keywords: _keywords, type: _type, location: _location, condition: _condition, min: _min, max: _max, negative: _negative, minFeedback: _minFeedback, maxFeedback: _maxFeedback, drange: _drange, categoryId: _categoryId })
                .done(function (data) {




                });


        });



    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error from your console shows that you didn't define the callback function startloading.

You can create an empty anonymous function

```
function(){}
```

in place of 'startloading' to test. If it works, you can then replace the empty function with the expected implementation of what you intend to do with startloading